# Reversing Scala Play Routes

Tags: scala, playframework

I am failing to reverse my route in Scala play for including a bootstrap css file inside my view.

Here is my link to the bootstrap file:

```
  <link href="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Here is my Route:

```
GET     /assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="public", file)
```

and here is my path to the file:

```
/public/bootstrap/dist/css$ ls
bootstrap.css      bootstrap-theme.css      index.html
bootstrap.min.css  bootstrap-theme.min.css  index.html.1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like your route is no valid slash is missing it should be

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```